it’s haram to sell products you don’t possess?
السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
I have a question, I started working with someone who imports bikes from Europe and China and resells them, he basically buys them at company prices, therefore reduced, (he has a VAT number) and resells them for higher prices, but the problem lies in the fact that he doesn't own the bikes but waits to be paid to then order them from these suppliers, i know about Rasulullah's hadith ﷺ where he says that you cannot sell something that you don't own, but he has contracts with these suppliers , so the bikes are actually shipped without problems, as soon as we receive the payment we pay the supplier, the bikes come to us, we look at them, we assemble them and send them to the customer and we keep the difference, I wanted to know if it was still haram, as narrated in that hadith or if it was halal by having contracts with these suppliers
jazakallah khair
